# Best Amazon linux AMI for using Ruby 2.3.3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I recently spun up a server that had Amazon's default Linux distro. I was disappointed to find that the version of Ruby I want (2.2.3) is unavailable. Is their a distro that will let me upgrade past the default version (ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux])

Comment: if you are fussy about the ruby version then you probably want to run rvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Amazon Linux, then you need to run this command to install Ruby 2.3:

```
sudo yum install ruby23
```

Comment: it says it's installed, however, when I run `ruby -v` it says: `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]` I restarted my env and still says the same thing. I might be missing something here...

Comment: You have multiple versions of ruby installed now, and ruby 2.0 is still the one configured as the default. To change the default version of ruby on your system run `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` and then select the version you want as the new default. You can also run `ls -l /etc/alternatives/ruby*` to see what versions are installed, and use the symbolic links there to run a specific version.

Comment: Running the Amazon Linux 2 AMI, I cannot install Ruby 2.3 (I only have 2.0 as noted above):

`$ sudo yum install -y ruby23
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                  | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
158 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package ruby23 available.
Error: Nothing to do`

I also tried this with --disableplugins=priorities (after running sudo yum update --disableplugsin=priorities) with no improvement.

Comment: If you are running Amazon LInux 2, instead of yum you have to use

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install ruby2.4`

Answer (score 9):

If you are running Amazon Linux 2, the newer Ruby versions are no longer available via yum. Instead, use:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install ruby2.4
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.